# Syncing with Trezor

Tags: trezor

Opened Trezor through MyEtherWallet for the first time. Trezor showed some addresses to send ether to, I sent all the coins I had from coinbase. The next time I opened Trezor and the same address was not in the list of addresses. In effect, I sent to the wrong address. I can view my ether in blockchain at that address but unable to retrieve via Trezor and haven't stored UTC or private key either. I can see my coins through MEW or Etherscan.io. Have I lost it all ?

(I am new to it as you can imagine ?). Please help.

Comment: Go through all your derivation paths, my ETH ended up being under the path for ETC.

Answer (score 0):

Your ether is hopefully (probably?) where it should be -- under your control. If I'm not mistaken, MyEtherWallet uses a [hierarchical deterministic](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet) (HD) wallet which means new addresses can be generated from a single key (which I assume is on your Trezor). For privacy reasons, many/most HD wallets generate new addresses every time a transaction is received at the most recently generated address. The single derivation key on your Trezor is sufficient for singing transactions from all of the addresses created in this fashion. That way, it's harder for an adversary to figure out how much ether/bitcoin/etc. is associated with a particular user.

I don't use either MyEtherWallet or a Trezor, but @tayvano can give you more firm answer regarding whether MyEtherWallet supports HD wallets.